# Weinberg Chapter 19.5, pion scattering amplitude derivations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, pions

I've been reading through Weinberg's Chapter 19, and am somewhat confused about how he manages to derive equations 19.5.25 and 19.5.29, which read:

$$\mathcal{M}_{abcd}^{(v=2)}=4F^{-2}\left[\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}(-p_A\cdot p_B-p_C\cdot p_D)+\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}(p_A\cdot p_C+p_B\cdot p_D)
\right.$$$$\left.
+\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}(p_A\cdot p_D+p_B\cdot p_C)\right]\tag{19.5.25}$$

and

$$\mathcal{M}_{abcd}^{(v=4)}=\frac{\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}}{F^4}\left[-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}s^2\ln(-s)
\right.$$$$\left.
-\frac{1}{12\pi^2}(u^2-s^2+3t^2)\ln(-t)-\frac{1}{12\pi^2}(t^2-s^2+3u^2)\ln(-u)
\right.$$$$\left.
+\frac{1}{3\pi^2}(s^2+t^2+u^2)\ln\Lambda^2-\frac{1}{2}c_4s^2-\frac{1}{4}c'_4(t^2+u^2)\right].\tag{19.5.29}$$

Would someone mind walking me through the derivation from the effective Lagrangian written in 19.5.19:

$$\mathcal{L}_\text{eff}=-\frac{F^2}{2}\vec{D}_\mu\vec{D}^\mu-\frac{c^4}{4}(\vec{D}_\mu\vec{D}^\mu)^2-\frac{c'_4}{4}(\vec{D}_\mu\cdot\vec{D}_\nu)(\vec{D}^\mu\cdot\vec{D}^\nu)-\dots,\tag{19.5.19}$$

where

$$\vec{D}_\mu=\frac{\partial_\mu\vec{\zeta}}{1+\vec{\zeta}^2}.$$